# PHP: Including a page from deeply nested directory hierarchy - performance issue

Tags: php, performance, include

Suppose, I'm about to include some page from a deeply nested directory hierarchy:

```
require '/path/to/project/views/forms/member/login/submit.php'
```

I've learned from operating system course that: each time we want to access/search a file: the `inode` (in unix systems) of each directory of the path is read to locate a file. So, is it also going to affect performance due to this kind of inclusion?

*Sorry if I've failed to be clear.*

Answer (score 2):

No. As far as performance issues go, this one is trivial enough to ignore.

Comment: really? Can you please explain or give some reference links where I can study?

Answer (score 2):

The time it'd take to read a file in a deeply nested directory is insignificant, based on current processing speeds for most computers. You wouldn't even notice it.

Comment: When the web app is going to run at shared servers, it will compete for CPU time with many other user's processes, so I will not be getting full CPU time for my application...

Answer (score 1):

There'll be a hit the FIRST time the directory path is traversed. After that, the stat() data is cached and overhead becomes minimal. There'd only be a bigger hit if/when the directories in question get pushed out of the stat cache and the data has to be re-read from disk.

Even then, the hit is very small. Consider that Apache has to do the exact same type of operations for EVERY hit on the server, as well as look for/load+parse .htaccess files and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

It's great you are tring to apply what you learned in an operating system course onto a web application however more often than not it's not going to be helpful. The levels an OS considers a "performance hit" vs an application communicating with the user over a network quite probably using a database is drastically different. In an OS, benchmarks counting microseconds is par for the course, a web app will probably be concerned about the millisecond-ten millisecond range really. Shaving off a couple ten microseconds will not even be measurable over the Internet. And yes, I am aware xhprof displays microseconds but that does not change anything.